# Does ObjC++ not catch exceptions by reference?

Tags: ios, ios6

I am using the following code in a ObjC++ wrapper class (.mm) and I notice that if I catch by reference the code fails randomly with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. On the other hand if I catch the object ("std::runtime_error error") it seem to be ok.

I am new to ObjC and I know that references are not used in ObjC, but I expect the compiler to work correctly in this case. Am I missing something?

```
catch(std::runtime_error &error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithCString:error.what() encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

ObjC++ must understand C++ references.

The problem is that your program reads another thread's memory asynchronously. For all I know, that thread has exited and its stack's memory along with it, or the stack memory was overwritten as the thread continued to execute -- thus, the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` (as *one* possible explanation).